# SignalR custom connection id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, signalr-hub

As we know the id of new connection can be setted using custom `IUserIdProvider`.

```
public string GetUserId(IRequest request)
{
    var context = request.GetHttpContext();
    ...
}
```

this method must return new connection Id.
My web application architecture is simple:

When uses connected, application generates guid (string) can be acessed from javascript variable. Then use generated guid in internals. So the question is how can i pass additional variable to signalR request to use it in `GetUserId` method.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let's clear up some terminology. When you are setting a [custom IUserIdProvider](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections#IUserIdProvider) you aren't actually changing the client's connection id, but instead the client's user id.

The client's connection id is always a GUID that is generated randomly by SignalR when each connection is started. This cannot be changed. To send a message to a client from a hub given its connection id, you would write: `Clients.Client(connectionId).myMethod(...)`.

The client's user id is the user's `IPrincipal.Identity.Name` by default, but this can be changed given a custom `IUserIdProvider`. Unlike a connection id, a user id can be shared by multiple connections. A common scenario where this can happen is when a single user has an app using SignalR open in multiple browser tabs. To send a message to a user from a hub given a user id, you would write: `Clients.User(userId).myMethod(...)`.

To answer your question, you can [set a query string parameter](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#querystring) that will be sent with every SignalR request which you can read in your `GetUserId` method. Be aware, that an attacker could easily set their own query string to whatever they want. This could make it possible to impersonate a user if you aren't careful about how you design your app.